# How to export a bulk data from snowflake to SQL Server table using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to export the Snowflake data (millions of records in a single table) using C# script and insert into a SQL Server table.

Bulk export operation times out. How to do this in batches in C# script?

Comment: why you need c# as bridge between two Database engines? link the two servers and let them do the job, no need for a third component to make things slower

Answer (score 2):

I have not done it before but what J.Salas is referring to (linking servers) looks like the best solution and is described [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6679/sql-server-linked-server-to-snowflake/) or [here](https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/how-to-set-up-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-snowflake).

If you can't do the above for some reason then it would be better to use a `COPY` to dump CSV files into a storage bucket and then load it into your SQL Server database with one of its bulk load utilities.

The main thing: don't build it yourself in C#, you'd just be re-inventing something that already exists. You can find something that is faster and better than what you could build yourself.